# c# - Entity Framework Core Cascade Delete on One-To-One Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, cascade, one-to-one

I have a one-to-one relationship between Service and Lexikon while the Service has a foreign key to Lexikon. My Service doesn't need a Lexikon so I made the LexikonID nullable. But my Lexikon can only exist if it is related to a Service so I made the navigation property [required]. I'm using Code First so EF builds my Database.

```
 public class Service
 {

    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    //Foreignkey
    public int? LexikonID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties

    public Lexikon Lexikon { get; set; }
 }

 public class Lexikon
 {
    public int LexikonID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    [Required]
    public SoftwareService SoftwareService { get; set; }

 }
```

I'm trying to delete the data automatically in table Lexikon if i delete my Service but unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this since I'm new to EF.

I tried this code in dbContext:

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareService>()
                .HasOne(l => l.Lexikon)
                .WithOne(s => s.SoftwareService)
                .HasForeignKey<SoftwareService>(l => l.LexikonID)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

but when I delete my Service the data in table Lexikon will still be in it. On the other hand when I delete the lexikon it will automatically delete the Service which is nice but I also want it to be happen to my Lexikon when I delete my Service.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the OnDelete-Method so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: do you have a answer for that Problem? i Face the same

Comment: My Service doesn't need a Lexikon -- so your model isn't correct. Service is the independent (principal) entity, Lexikon is the dependent entity and it should have a foreign key to Service. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72977237/861716.

Answer (score 1):

Did you generate the database from your model? You have to, because EF generates an ON DELETE CASCADE constraint. Otherwise, you will need to add it by hand. I wrote a post on this problem, for EF pre-Core, but it still applies: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/entity-framework-pitfalls-cascade-deletes.

Comment: Yes my database is generated from my model by the entityframework

Comment: In that case, you should have the constraint. There's nothing more to it, really.

Comment: One more thing: you are mixing attributes with code configuration, the latter takes prevalence, so I think you need to indicate that one of the endpoints is required.

Comment: When I look at my Database both tables have no ON DELETE CASCADE constraints. I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean with mixing attributes with code configuration. Can you tell me where I'm making this error.

Comment: Then, they weren't generated by EF. Try to do that using migrations.

Comment: EF Core documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete: "This relies on a corresponding cascade behavior being present in the database to ensure data that is not tracked by the context is also deleted."

Comment: CASCADE DELETE in RDBMS are single directional (from principal to dependent). Hence you can't configure cascade delete in both directions.

Comment: @RicardoPeres OP :) *but when I delete my Service the data in table Lexikon will still be in it. On the other hand when I delete the lexikon it will automatically delete the Service which is nice but I also want it to be happen to my Lexikon when I delete my Service.*

Comment: @JoeJonsman: having both [Required] and code configuration. You can replace the [Required] attribute with the equivalent code.

Comment: @IvanStoev: only one endpoint can be made required, of course. The other can be configured to cascade or not, but this is achieved by an ON DELETE CASCADE constraint in SQL Server, which is generated automatically for us *if we let EF generate the database*.

Comment: @RicardoPeres The way I read the OP explanation, the cascade delete is properly set up in the database and works in `Lexikon` -> `Service` directon. But OP **also** wants it to work in the opposite direction, which I'm saying is not possible to be achieved through configuration.

Comment: So I'm trying to add the ON DELETE CASCADE constraint by hand like you showed me in your link but there are no methods like 'hasOptional' or 'willCascadeOnDelete'. Also there is no Class 'DbModelBuilder'. I only have 'ModelBuilder'. Do I need a special Library or something like that? I'm working with ef Core 2.0 by the way

Comment: No, these were EF pre-Core methods, but there are equivalent Core ones. DbModelBuilder is now ModelBuilder.

Comment: "I'm trying to delete the data automatically in table Lexikon if i delete my Service" - I only see one direction.

Comment: @IvanStoev I may have confused you with my sentence. Yes I can delete my Lexikon so it automatically deletes the Service which is related to it. But that's not my goal. I want it to be the other way around. So when I delete my Service it should automatically delete my Lexikon which doesn't happen with my code I posted

Comment: You can't have both at the same time! :-)

Comment: @JoeJonsman Then you'd probably put the FK in the wrong place. It should be in Lexikon. Take a look at [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes I think you're right. When I put the FK in Lexikon it works. Thank you very much! I guess there is no solution when I let the FK in Service

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible this direction, only from principal to child