# EF Core One-to-One Optional Relation with Cascade Delete - FK on Principal Entity

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two Entities and want to configure a 1:1 optional relationship that supports cascade one delete. One `Episode` can have one optional `Release`, but a `Release` can never exist without an `Episode`. So `Episode` should be the principal entity and `Release` the dependant entity, also whenever an `Episode` is deleted, the possible `Release` should also be deleted.

But since i have a lot of business logic that depends on whether the `Episode` has a `Release` and what the possible details are, i need the FK to be on `Episode` rather than on `Release` an do a lot of checks like `someEpisode.ReleaseId.HasValue`.

```
public class Episode
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // a lot of episode infos...

    public Release? Release { get; set; }
    public Guid? ReleaseId { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Release
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // a lot of release infos
}
```

But using this entity definitions, i could not find a way to configure EF Core to meet my expectations stated above. `Episode` is always considered als dependant entity. As a workaround i currently delete the `Release` manually whenever an `Episode` has to be deleted.

Is it maybe impossible to place an FK on a principal entity, regardless of EF Core?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried going full brute force through fluent API on this? `builder.Entity<Release>().HasOne(r=>r.Edition).WithOne(e=>e.Release).HasForeignKey<Edition>(e=>e.ReleaseId).IsOptional()`

Comment: *"Is it maybe impossible to place an FK on a principal entity"* Indeed. FK means I am referencing something else. Well, the referenced is called principal, and referencing (with FK) - dependent. This is relational database principle, nothing to do with EF Core.

Comment: But... why do you think the FK must be on `Episode`. It should be on `Release` (and standard shared PK which is also a FK). You can still have *navigation property* `Episode.Release`, it has nothing to with where is the FK.

Answer (score -1):

In 1:n associations it seems more intuitive to us that the independent entity, the parent, doesn't have a foreign key to its children. We immediately sense that *one* foreign key for *many* children can't be right. The children have a foreign key to the parent, obviously.

In 1:1 associations we somehow get lured into an object-oriented mindset more easily. It seems natural that if an independent (principal) entity owns a dependent entity, the former should "own" the foreign key. However, just as in 1:n, the dependent entity is the child and, hence, has a foreign key (see [object–relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_impedance_mismatch)).

With this in mind, it's clear how the model and the mappings should be coded. *For example* (because there are options):

```cs
class Episode
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Release? Release { get; set; }
}

class Release
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Episode Episode { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Release>()
    .HasOne(r => r.Episode)
    .WithOne(e => e.Release)
    .HasForeignKey<Release>();
```

The line `HasForeignKey<Release>()` turns `Release` into the dependent entity. By default, EF creates a *shared primary key* association in which `Release`'s primary key is also the foreign key:

```sql
CONSTRAINT [FK_Release_Episode_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Episode] 
    ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

You can also have a separate foreign key:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Release>()
    .HasOne(r => r.Episode)
    .WithOne(e => e.Release)
    .HasForeignKey<Release>("EpisodeID");
```

...which creates a `Release.EpisodeID` foreign key field in the database and a *shadow property* in the class model.

Another option is to create a *foreign key relationship* (reference and foreign key property in the class model):

```cs
class Release
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EpisodeId { get; set; }
    public Episode Episode { get; set; }
}
```

...which EF understands by convention, i.e. without explicit mapping, but could be mapped explicitly as:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Release>()
    .HasOne(r => r.Episode)
    .WithOne(e => e.Release)
    .HasForeignKey<Release>(r => r.EpisodeId);
```

Finally, it's not necessary to have both reference properties in both classes. Either `Episode.Release` or `Release.Episode` can be omitted. In the latter case, mappings should have `modelBuilder.Entity<Release>()` as starting point.